# How do I get proper data while saving to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form made that appears to be connected to a mysql database. When I enter information into the form and submit it, it registers in the database as "0000-00-00" and the data is returned as "0000-00-00". None of the actual data is showing up. Any Ideas?

connection.php:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';
$db = 'sm_residents';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($db);
?>
```

Create.php:

```
<?php
include ('connection.php');

$FirstName= $_POST['inputFirstName'];
$LastName= $_POST['inputLastName'];
$Address= $_POST['inputAddress'];
$Birthday= $_POST['inputBirthday'];
$FormerResidence= $_POST['inputFormerResidence'];
$Career= $_POST['inputCareer'];
$Education= $_POST['inputEducation'];
$SpecialInterests= $_POST['inputSpecialInterests'];

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
} else {
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                           "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    }
}

Picture= $_FILES["file"]["name"];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO residents             (`ID`,`FirstName`,`LastName`,`Address`,`Birthday`,`FormerResidence`,`Career`,`Education`,`SpecialInterests`,`Picture`)
                         VALUES(NULL,'$FirstName','$LastName','$Address','$Birthday','$FormerResidence','$Career','$Education','$SpecialInterests','$Picture')") or die(mysql_error());

?>
<script> window.location = "index.php"; </script>
```

Index.php:

```
<?php
 include ('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "Please Fill Out The Form";
    //header ('Location: create.php');
} else {
    //echo "User Has Been Added";
    //header('Location: create.php');
}
?>
<h1>Add A Resident</h1>
    <form action="create.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputLastName">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Address">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputBirthday">Birthday</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputBirthday">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputFormerResidence">Former Residence</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFormerResidence" placeholder="Former        Residence">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputCareer">Career</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCareer" placeholder="Career">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEducation">Education</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEducation" placeholder="Education">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputSpecialInterests">Special Interests</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSpecialInterests" placeholder="Special Interests">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputFile">File input</label>
<input type="file" id="inputFile">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Which variable in the code are you working with?

Comment: You're missing the `$` before `Picture=`. How is this even running?

Comment: You don't have an input form element named `submit` so I don't know how that even works `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "Please Fill Out The Form";` doesn't make sense. Plus this `Picture= $_FILES["file"]["name"];` is that a typo? If not, add the `$` to `Picture` - `$Picture= $_FILES["file"]["name"];` - If your data comes out as zeros, check your column's type.

Comment: I guess you're talking about the birthday field. What are you entering into the field?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `create.php` doesn't look for a field named `submit`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- He already has `or die(mysql_error())`.

Comment: @Barmar code analyst....

Comment: @Barmar I don't know why OP's using `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "Please Fill Out The Form";` if it doesn't have a named input to start with or match. I guess it's irrelevant then.

Comment: There aren't even any named elements for the inputs, so nothing is going to go through, they're all IDs. Use [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and debug this.

Comment: I don't know why he's doing that in `index.php`, either. But it can't affect `create.php`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good catch. To OP: You need `name="fieldName"` in all the `<input>` fields. if you had error reporting enabled, you would be seeing lots of warnings about undefined indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll make this an answer: (or a BIG `90% / 95%` partial at best)

> *None of the actual data is showing up*

There aren't even any named elements for the inputs, so nothing is going to go through, they're all IDs.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
```

which should read as

```
<input type="text" name="inputFirstName" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then do the same for the others by "naming" them as I did above.

PHP is looking for named elements, not IDs which cannot be relied upon.

This also doesn't have a name `<input type="file" id="inputFile">`

change to: `<input type="file" name="file" id="inputFile">`

as per `$_FILES["file"]`

---

- Use [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

while placing the following underneath your opening `<?php` tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

which will throw many `Undefined index` warnings with your present code.

---

Also as pointed out by Barmar [`in his comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779094/how-do-i-get-data-to-submit-to-a-mysql-database/25779239#comment40317199_25779094), you're missing a `$` for `Picture= $_FILES["file"]["name"];` unless that was a typo, it should read as:

```
$Picture= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

---

In regards to *it registers in the database as "`0000-00-00`"* make sure your column is of the correct type to accomodate a DATE.

Comment: +1. MySQL is expecting string values inserted into columns of datatpye DATE (DATETIME, TIMESTAMP) to be in format like `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'`. Best approach is to format these string values in appropriate format in client code. But if we need to supply values in a different format, we can make use of MySQL `STR_TO_DATE` function in the values list, e.g. `STR_TO_DATE('9/10/2014','%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you. +1 on your comment, very well written.

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting first your Birthdate:

```
 $Birthday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['inputBirthday']));
```

Comment: It was a combination of needing to name the elements and reformatting the Birthdate. Thanks for taking the time to read through my junk code! I'm still pretty new at this.

Comment: That's good to hear @ChrisCarr. We all start from scratch and we need to persevere in order to grow in our chosen field. GOD bless you and Happy coding!

Comment: @ChrisCarr I am totally baffled. First you accept my answer, then this one. It's as if my answer means nothing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Both answers were beneficial. I accepted your answer first and then this one. I'm new to this and I wasn't aware I couldn't accept both answers. Thanks so much for your help though!